# FileNotFoundException when trying to obtain uri path

Tags: java, android, uri, android-image, filenotfoundexception

I just came back to this one particular piece of code because it seems to keep returning null on one of our devices. The line of code is this:

```
public static Uri getUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
        Uri finalUri = null;
        if (path != null) {
            finalUri = Uri.parse(path);
        }
        return finalUri;
    }
```

The error log shows:

> ```
> Failed to insert image
> ```
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:620)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:988)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:735)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:711)
>   at
>   android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:958)
>   at com.scanlibrary.Utils.getUri(Utils.java:31) at
>   com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.postImagePick(PickImageFragment.java:172)
>   at
>   com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.onActivityResult(PickImageFragment.java:167)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6871) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4751) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4798)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:219) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

After going through the debugger the error seems to come from line 31 which contains:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
```

My problem with this is that it seems to work perfectly on some devices whilst on others it continues to give me these issues. I can't seem to figure out how to go about fixing this particular bug. I have tried going through the source code on any part that uses the `Utils.getUri()` portion but I've yet to understand how this works and why it is giving me an issue, specially since it works on our other devices.

Comment: Why are you using `insertImage()` in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare the code was written by another developer, and since he is gone I was left with the entire project to deal with.

Comment: OK. What is the point behind having `getUri()` in the first place? What are you doing with this `Uri`?

Comment: For what I can take thus far, the app takes a picture, it passes through this static method and gets the URI in order to save it to the system or modify it later. The uri is needed for how he coded the handling of the file. This is as much as I can gather from what I have read thus far (only been looking at it for the last hour) my issue is with the path String being null

Comment: @AvadaKedavra The OP incorrectly wrote `NullPointerException`. But it is actually a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: When there is really a NullPointerException occuring at this line, then it can just happen because the `context` parameter of the method is null. So you might want to find out why this is the case.

Comment: @Rotwang you are correct I did write the wrong kind of exception being thrown. I apologize for that and thank you for editing it to the correct one. Apparently from what I can gather this can also happen for permissions not being set which is interesting considering that all the permissions had already been put in place.

Comment: `all the permissions had already been put in place.` ... in the Manifest only? That's not enough on Marshmallow and later versions.

Comment: not only on manifest but during runtime, permissions are asked adequately and I can check on the app manager that all permissions had been granted accordingly. This works on all other devices that we have tested except for this one.

Comment: Actually gentlement I just did a factory reset on that device and now it worked...............this is why I sometimes hate Android development with its native base.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that occurred for me with API 16 or 17 and not with API 23.

While in my app the user press Home and then he try to open an assigned file type in the file browser or attached in an email then the exception occurred when receiving the Intent .

Instead if the Activity was destroyed, for example pressing back key, and then we open the associated file then it worked well.

The only solution I found is in the exception catch to ask the user to close the application and try again, if he answer OK then I called finish().

It seems that the problem occurs when an existing Activity receives a second Intent, but works fine when that intent is the one fresh that creates the Activity, but as I said at the beginning with API 23 or 24 worked well.

Hope it help.